# Laravel eloquent save

Tags: laravel

I am trying to change a value on save

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::saving(function ($formRow) {

            $formRow->sales = 1;         

    });
}
```

But the weird part is that its not changing the sales to 1, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the call to the parent's `boot` method:

```
public static function boot()
{
    // add this
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($formRow) {

            $formRow->sales = 1;         

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the [`save`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L530) method on the model itself:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
```